# Join across many same tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Theese are my tables:

```
users
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  | Bob  |
| 2  | Adam |

products
| id | Name     |
|----|----------|
| 1  | Keyboard |
| 2  | Mouse    |

orders
| user_id | product_id |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 1          |
| 1       | 2          |
| 2       | 1          |
```

I want to query all `Bob` orders. I can use that:

```
select 
  user_id, 
  product_id 
from 
  orders o 
  inner join users u on u.id = o.user_id 
  inner join products p on p.id = o.product_id 
where 
  o.user_id = 1
```

Now, for performance reasons, multiple `orders` tables has been added:

```
orders
| user_id | product_id |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 1          |
| 1       | 2          |
| 2       | 1          |

orders_2
| user_id | product_id |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 4          |
| 6       | 2          |
| 1       | 7          |

orders_3
| user_id | product_id |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 8          |
| 2       | 2          |
| 4       | 1          |
```

How can I get all Bob's orders now? Every `order_x` has the same design as `order`. Is it possible to join them all in 1 query?

Comment: Just use `UNION` like here : https://sqlize.online/s/P

Comment: This is the same solution as @Ananth MK, but he suggested `union all` instead `union`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter and union all orders together and then join with product.

```
select 
  user_id, 
  product_id 
from 
  (
    select * from orders o1 where o1.user_id = 1    
    union all 
    select * from orders_2 o2 where o2.user_id = 1
    union all 
    select * from orders_3 o3 where o3.user_id = 1
  ) AS o
inner join users u on u.id = o.user_id 
inner join products p on p.id = o.product_id
```